# Induction principle for `le`

Tags: coq, agda, induction, parametric-polymorphism

For the inductive type `nat`, the generated induction principle uses the constructors `O` and `S` in its statement:

```
Inductive nat : Set :=  O : nat | S : nat -> nat

nat_ind
 : forall P : nat -> Prop,
   P 0 ->
   (forall n : nat, P n -> P (S n)) -> forall n : nat, P n
```

But for `le`, the generated statement does not uses the constructors `le_n` and `le_S`:

```
Inductive le (n : nat) : nat -> Prop :=
le_n : n <= n | le_S : forall m : nat, n <= m -> n <= S m

le_ind
 : forall (n : nat) (P : nat -> Prop),
   P n ->
   (forall m : nat, n <= m -> P m -> P (S m)) ->
   forall n0 : nat, n <= n0 -> P n0
```

However it is possible to state and prove an induction principle following the same shape as the one for `nat`:

```
Lemma le_ind' : forall n (P : forall m, le n m -> Prop),
P n (le_n n) ->
(forall m (p : le n m), P m p -> P (S m) (le_S n m p)) ->
forall m (p : le n m), P m p.
Proof.
fix H 6; intros; destruct p.
apply H0.
apply H1, H.
apply H0.
apply H1.
Qed.
```

I guess the generated one is more convenient. But how does Coq chooses the  shape for its generated induction principle? If there is any rule, I cannot find them in the reference manual. What about other proof assistants such as Agda?

Comment: I didn't understand this: `the generated statement does not uses the constructors le_n and le_S`. When doing induction on `n <= m` you do consider two cases: `le_n` and `le_S`.

Comment: @dyukha I am talking about the statement (i.e. the type) of `le_ind`. You can clearly see that `le_n` and `le_S` do not occur.

Comment: Try to find access to "Interactive Theorem Proving and Program Development, CoqArt: The Calculus of Inductive Constructions" what you are asking for is described in chapt. 14.

Comment: I only found the French version online and Chapter 14 seems to be about coinduction. By the way, it is a pity that such a great book is not better publicized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually generate an induction principle for an inductive type by using the command `Scheme` (see the [documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/user-extensions/proof-schemes.html#generation-of-induction-principles-with-scheme)).

The command comes in two flavours :

- `Scheme scheme := Induction for Sort Prop` generates the standard induction scheme.
- `Scheme scheme := Minimality for Sort Prop` generates a simplified induction scheme more suited to inductive predicates.

If you define an inductive type in `Type`, the generated induction principle is of the first kind. If you define an inductive type in `Prop` (i.e. an inductive predicate), the generated induction principle is of the second kind.

To obtain the induction principle that you want in the case of `le`, you can define it in `Type`:

```
Inductive le (n : nat) : nat -> Type :=
| le_n : le n n
| le_S : forall m : nat, le n m -> le n (S m).

Check le_ind.
(* forall (n : nat) (P : forall n0 : nat, le n n0 -> Prop),
   P n (le_n n) ->
   (forall (m : nat) (l : le n m), P m l -> P (S m) (le_S n m l)) ->
   forall (n0 : nat) (l : le n n0), P n0 l
*)
```

or you can manually ask Coq to generate the expected induction principle:

```
Inductive le (n : nat) : nat -> Prop :=
| le_n : le n n
| le_S : forall m : nat, le n m -> le n (S m).

Check le_ind.
(* forall (n : nat) (P : nat -> Prop),
   P n ->
   (forall m : nat, le n m -> P m -> P (S m)) ->
   forall n0 : nat, le n n0 -> P n0
*)

Scheme le_ind2 := Induction for le Sort Prop.
Check le_ind2.
(* forall (n : nat) (P : forall n0 : nat, le n n0 -> Prop),
   P n (le_n n) ->
   (forall (m : nat) (l : le n m), P m l -> P (S m) (le_S n m l)) ->
   forall (n0 : nat) (l : le n n0), P n0 l
*)
```